# Erro ao adicionar ionic-platform-web-client

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Tenho um projeto Ionic funcionando perfeitamente.
Estas são as versões que estou utilizando:

- Cordova CLI: 5.3.3
- Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
- Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
- Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
- Node: v4.2.1
- Ionic Bower: 1.3.1

Entretanto ao adicionar o plugin `$ bower install --save ionic-platform-web-client`, tenho o seguinte erro:

> vendor.min.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: ionic is not defined

Estranho que isso acontece somente pelo fato de adicionar a biblioteca, ainda não estou usando em lugar nenhum.

O que poderia ser isso?

Comment: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-platform-web-client/issues/10

Comment: Descobri o problema. Estou usando uma estrutura customizada para o **lib** assim o [Automatic Code Modification](http://docs.ionic.io/v2.0.0-beta/docs/io-service-modules#automatic-code-modification) não funcionava.
Obrigado pela ajuda.